# Proving that representation is differentiable

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be a real or complex finite-dimensional vector space, and let $\pi$ be a continuous representation of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ on V with:

$$\pi(t + s) = \pi(t) \pi(s), t, s \in \mathbb{R} \: \: (1)$$
$$\pi(0) = I \: \:(2)$$

a) Prove that $\pi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow L(V) is differentiable.

There is also a b) part, but I've solved that with assuming that $\pi$ is differentiable. From (1) it follows that it's enough to show differentiability in zero.

There is a pretty strange hint following the a) part... something about proving that there exists $\alpha > 0$ so that operator

$$B = \int_0^{\alpha} \pi(t) dt$$

is regular. I can't really understand what it means to take an integral of a linear operator, we haven't defined that anywhere. But it someone has an idea what that notation could mean, please explain it to me.

Comment: What is regular?

Comment: @MarcPalm regular = invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $B: v \mapsto \int_0^\alpha \pi(t) v d t$

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed.